# Proper way to receive a server-side event when directory change for jsTree

Tags: symfony, ftp, jstree

I have a project with Symfony 2 and in one page I have a [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) which shows the files of a directory.

I need to refresh that tree when a file is removed or added in the ftp server.

I was thinking in the possibility of doing that with [Server-side Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-eventsource-20111020/). However I don't think it's the optimal way for performance. Because I will have to sent a ftp request every X seconds to know if that directory have changed.

What other alternatives do I have ?

Comment: Have you seen websockets?

Comment: I know just the theory of the web sockets but I haven't implemented it yet. However I think I will have the same performance problem. I mean the flow on the server side it will be the same as SSE isn't it?

Comment: What I am about to offer will not solve the problem, just a clarification - whatever method you choose (especially if you need near real-time notifications) will put load on your server - just choose what you can use depending on your clients (I believe websockets have good enough support). But if you do not need to know about the changes in real time (if they happen rarely) you can assume everything is the same and only refresh the tree when an error occurs and also on a fixed interval (use the `massload` plugin to refresh in one request).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you give me a link of "massload plugin" I couldn't find it on the net...

Comment: nevermind I found it http://www.jstree.com/plugins/